# Why is 'Null is not an Object' showing in console when there is an object?

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel

I am getting this error in my web console:

```
null is not an object (evaluating 'selected.addEventListener')
```

It is within a JavaScript file I have called `landing.js` and it is used for a custom select drop down. This is a photo of the error:

[image]

This is the raw code:

```js
const selected = document.querySelector(".selected");
const optionsContainer = document.querySelector(".options-container");
const optionsList = document.querySelectorAll(".option");

selected.addEventListener("click", () => {
    optionsContainer.classList.toggle("active");
});

optionsList.forEach( o => {
    o.addEventListener("click", () => {
        selected.innerHTML = o.querySelector("label").innerHTML;
        optionsContainer.classList.remove("active");
    });
});
```

I don't understand why this error is happening because I have used this exact same code in a different project and it works. THe project is created in laravel and uses `blade.php` templates and this is the 3 different blade files:

1. webpageTemplate.blade.php:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="Mobile Masters Shop" content="This is the header section  for the shop in mobile masters">
    <meta name="author" content="Ross Currie">
    <meta name="description" content="Mobile Gaming Accessories">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
    <meta name="keywords" content="Ferg, iFerg, Gaming, Mobile, Accessories, Youtube, Mobile Master, Shop">

    <!-- CSRF Token -->
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

    <title>{{ config('app.name', 'Mobile Mastery') }} | @yield('title')</title>

    <!-- Scripts -->
    @yield('scripts')

    <!-- Styles -->
    @yield('design')
    <link href="{{ asset('design/Add_Ons/Animations.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="{{ asset('design/Add_Ons/Fonts.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
<div class="app" id="app">
    @if(str_contains(url()->current(), '/'))
        @include('body.landing_body')
    @endif
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

2. landing_header.blade.php

```html
@extends('webpageTemplate')

@section('title')
    Home
@endsection

@section('scripts')
    <script src="{{ asset('scripts/landing.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/11bae6a58f.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
@endsection

@section('design')
    <link href="{{ asset('design/landing/Landing_Main.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="{{ asset('design/landing/Landing_Responsive.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
@endsection
```

3. landing_body.blade.php

```html
<!-- Container to position stuff in middle of screen -->
<div class="centerScreen">
    <div class="logo">
        <div>
            <img class="logoWidth rotate-center" src="{{ asset('img/logo/IconOnly.png') }}" alt="Mobile Mastery Icon">
        </div>

        <div class="title">
            <img class="logoNameWidth" src="{{ asset('img/logo/LogoNameWhite.png') }}" alt="Mobile Mastery Title">
        </div>

        <div class="CountryInput">
            <div class="select-box">
                <div class="options-container">
                    <div class="option">
                        <input type="radio" class="radio" id="United States" name="country"> <label for="United States">United States</label>
                    </div>

                    <div class="option">
                        <input type="radio" class="radio" id="United Kingdom" name="country"> <label for="United Kingdom And Ireland">United Kingdom And Ireland</label>
                    </div>

                    <div class="option">
                        <input type="radio" class="radio" id="Philippines" name="country"> <label for="Philippines">Philippines</label>
                    </div>

                    <div class="option">
                        <input type="radio" class="radio" id="India" name="country"> <label for="India">India</label>
                    </div>

                    <div class="option">
                        <input type="radio" class="radio" id="Indonesia" name="country"> <label for="Indonesia">Indonesia</label>
                    </div>

                    <div class="option">
                        <input type="radio" class="radio" id="Malaysia" name="country"> <label for="Malaysia">Malaysia</label>
                    </div>

                    <div class="option">
                        <input type="radio" class="radio" id="Mexico" name="country"> <label for="Mexico">Mexico</label>
                    </div>

                    <div class="option">
                        <input type="radio" class="radio" id="Singapore" name="country"> <label for="Singapore">Singapore</label>
                    </div>

                    <div class="option">
                        <input type="radio" class="radio" id="Germany" name="country"> <label for="Germany">Germany</label>
                    </div>

                    <div class="option">
                        <input type="radio" class="radio" id="Brazil" name="country"> <label for="Brazil">Brazil</label>
                    </div>

                    <div class="option">
                        <input type="radio" class="radio" id="Canada" name="country"> <label for="Canada">Canada</label>
                    </div>

                    <div class="option">
                        <input type="radio" class="radio" id="Italy" name="country"> <label for="Italy">Italy</label>
                    </div>

                    <div class="option">
                        <input type="radio" class="radio" id="Colombia" name="country"> <label for="Colombia">Colombia</label>
                    </div>

                    <div class="option">
                        <input type="radio" class="radio" id="Australia" name="country"> <label for="Australia">Australia</label>
                    </div>

                    <div class="option">
                        <input type="radio" class="radio" id="South Africa" name="country"> <label for="South Africa">South Africa</label>
                    </div>

                    <div class="option">
                        <input type="radio" class="radio" id="France" name="country"> <label for="France">France</label>
                    </div>

                    <div class="option">
                        <input type="radio" class="radio" id="Pakistan" name="country"> <label for="Pakistan">Pakistan</label>
                    </div>

                    <div class="option">
                        <input type="radio" class="radio" id="Bangladesh" name="country"> <label for="Bangladesh">Bangladesh</label>
                    </div>

                    <div class="option">
                        <input type="radio" class="radio" id="Spain" name="country"> <label for="Spain">Spain</label>
                    </div>

                    <div class="option">
                        <input type="radio" class="radio" id="United Arab Emirates" name="country"> <label for="United Arab Emirates">United Arab Emirates</label>
                    </div>

                    <div class="option">
                        <input type="radio" class="radio" id="Netherlands" name="country"> <label for="Netherlands">Netherlands</label>
                    </div>

                    <div class="option">
                        <input type="radio" class="radio" id="Sri Lanka" name="country"> <label for="Sri Lanka">Sri Lanka</label>
                    </div>

                    <div class="option">
                        <input type="radio" class="radio" id="Russia" name="country"> <label for="Russia">Russia</label>
                    </div>

                    <div class="option">
                        <input type="radio" class="radio" id="Trinidad & Tobago" name="country"> <label for="Trinidad & Tobago">Trinidad & Tobago</label>
                    </div>

                    <div class="option">
                        <input type="radio" class="radio" id="Saudi Arabia" name="country"> <label for="Saudi Arabia">Saudi Arabia</label>
                    </div>

                    <div class="option">
                        <input type="radio" class="radio" id="Thailand" name="country"> <label for="Thailand">Thailand</label>
                    </div>

                    <div class="option">
                        <input type="radio" class="radio" id="Peru" name="country"> <label for="Peru">Peru</label>
                    </div>

                    <div class="option">
                        <input type="radio" class="radio" id="New Zealand" name="country"> <label for="New Zealand">New Zealand</label>
                    </div>

                    <div class="option">
                        <input type="radio" class="radio" id="Vietnam" name="country"> <label for="Vietnam">Vietnam</label>
                    </div>

                    <div class="option">
                        <input type="radio" class="radio" id="Japan" name="country"> <label for="Japan">Japan</label>
                    </div>

                    <div class="option">
                        <input type="radio" class="radio" id="Egypt" name="country"> <label for="Egypt">Egypt</label>
                    </div>

                    <div class="option">
                        <input type="radio" class="radio" id="Argentina" name="country"> <label for="Argentina">Argentina</label>
                    </div>

                    <div class="option">
                        <input type="radio" class="radio" id="Helpful Links" name="Helpful Links"> <label for="Other">Helpful Links</label>
                    </div>

                    <div class="option">
                        <input type="radio" class="radio" id="Other" name="country"> <label for="Other">Other...</label>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="selected">
                    Select Country To Continue:
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <button onclick="goAfterSelect()" class="landingButton">
            Continue <span class="far fa-arrow-alt-circle-right continue-arrow"></span>
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most commons explaination is that `const selected = document.querySelector(".selected");` returns null.

You can just check by adding

```
console.log({selected});
```

right after the definition.

So it can happen because you run this code before dom is ready, most common error when using JQuery. See the [doc](https://api.jquery.com/ready/) and put all your code inside

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  // All your code here
});
```

Comment: Forgot to say that this had worked!

Answer (score 1):

Element is not created yet.
Include your script at the end of your body tag and it would solve your problem.
Or you can wrap all your js code in a function and assign it to `document.onload`.

Like this:

```js
document.onload = function(){
  const selected = document.querySelector(".selected");
  const optionsContainer = document.querySelector(".options-container");
  const optionsList = document.querySelectorAll(".option");

  selected.addEventListener("click", () => {
      optionsContainer.classList.toggle("active");
  });

  optionsList.forEach( o => {
      o.addEventListener("click", () => {
          selected.innerHTML = o.querySelector("label").innerHTML;
          optionsContainer.classList.remove("active");
      });
  });
};
```